# How to suppress "warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class" with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javac

How to suppress "warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class" with Gradle?

- This not a duplicate question
- This not during Proguard nor do I want to suppress using Proguard
- I would like to suppress doing normal `./gradlew assembleDebug`  (since this is `assertj-core` - `./gradlew testDebug`)

**Dependency:**

```
dependencies {
   testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1"
}
```

**Warning:**

```
Dex: warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.reflect.FastClassEmitter$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

**Something like:**

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    configure(options) {
        compilerArgs << "-Xlint:-options"    // Turn off "missing" bootclasspath warning
    }
}
```

What `compilerArgs` can I add to suppress this warning?

**References:**

- I have an answer here but none of these suppress this warning: [How do I suppress warnings when compiling an android library with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148513/how-do-i-suppress-warnings-when-compiling-an-android-library-with-gradle)

Comment: Why not using proguard?

Comment: @cipley This happens on assemble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to use a third party lib a while ago. That lib was compiled for Java 1.3. I was able to fix it by getting the source of that lib and build a jar file on my own. This works only, of course, if the sources to that lib are available and ready for build.

Comment: Alright. I rather not compile and repackage of `assertj-core`. I just want to "silence" Gradle.

Comment: By chance I stumbled upon another, similar question. Maybe this answer to that question is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40173052/5956451

Comment: I use `assertj-core` for unit tests. This does not get compiled into the app and so I will not run proguard against it.

Answer (score 0):

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` with replacing the unchecked does not help?
More examples are here:
http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/suppresswarnings-annotation-examples

Comment: This is not an unchecked exception.