# How to get 'android.enableR8=true' to pass without warning?

Tags: android

I added the new setting:

```
android.enableR8 = true
```

to my Gradle file but I got the following warning from the compiler

```
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is experimental and unsupported.
```

any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171304/5726600

Comment: in android studio 3.2?

Comment: yes 3.2 canary 14

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a new feature. The warning is just that. It already works.

The warning will disappear in a future version of Android Studio.

Comment: i am using android studio 3.3.0, and the warning still exist

Comment: 3.4.0 only warns if used fullMode, i.e. `android.enableR8.fullMode = true`

Comment: Still warns in Android Studio 3.5......The option setting 'android.enableR8.fullMode=true' is experimental and unsupported.

Comment: It still warns with AS 3.6.1 and the warning now was valid for me, as with this update constructors marked as keep started being removed. Had to disable it to make my code work again.

Comment: 3 years later, it's still experimental in Arctic Fox Beta 1 with gradle 7.0.0 :(

Comment: 3 years later in 2021. it's still warns but now it says
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: still warns in 2022

Comment: Still warn in 2023

Answer (score 15):

Just delete `android.enableR8=true` from your `gradle.properties` and Sync again.

Wait till sync is finished, then you will find everything is working fine...

Comment: that means the android tool may fallback to proguard or may not obfuscate and optimise code at all.

Comment: @ir2pid R8 is now enabled by default for both app and Android library projects using Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 and higher.