# Supressed warnings of a third party library

Tags: android, android-logcat, jetbrains-ide, suppress-warnings

I've added a library in my project which produces lot's of long warnings that get's all of my logcat and hardly I can find the warnings I really care about.
I use filtering and searching but it's still annoying.
I can't remove library from project and I can't fix warning for now.
How Can I supress this warning?

app/gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'OneSignal-3.6.3', ext: 'aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Warning :
https://gist.github.com/zeynaliAli/45f0e8a64991fbc85798ea1f11456298

Comment: Please post gradle,logcat here also

Comment: Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148513/how-do-i-suppress-warnings-when-compiling-an-android-library-with-gradle?rq=1

Comment: @quicklearner I have added a lib in gradle and I have a really long warning does them help anyone ?

Comment: @GokulNathKP in mentioned question problem is compiler warnings and for me it's **the library itself** warnings, also I don't want to ignore all the warning just this specific warning or if it's not possible just the library warnings.