# How to ignore this warning?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to suppress this warning when I build a [sample app](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/main/unit/BasicSample) provided on Android Github :

```
Note: app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

What I've tried so far is just everything proposed in Stackoverflow, including :

```
gradle clean build -x lint
```

or in MainActivity.java :

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@SuppressLint("all")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

What else can I try ?

Comment: Don't use deprecated APIs?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to ignore warnings.  It is a worse idea to configure your build or source code to suppress the warnings.  A deprecation warning is telling you that your code is liable to break in the future if you haven't stopped using the deprecated thing.  You should not be hiding that ...

Comment: If the sample app you are playing with has deprecation warnings, you should probably look for something that isn't out of date.  Certainly, you don't want to copy the out-of-date usages into >your< code.

Comment: All these comments are obvious and not relevant for my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Preferences** >> **Editor** >> **Inspections** >> **Java** (or **Kotlin**) >> **Code maturity** >> Uncheck *Deprecated API usage*

[image: Ignore Deprecated Warning]

Comment: Ok, thanks, now how does it translate into a gradle command line (I'm not using Android Studio) ?

Comment: All relevant commands can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171304/9246764

Comment: yes I know this article, there are many commands, but none of them is working for my little example. I'm providing full code, have u tried your UI method or any of these commands ? Does something work for you ?